# Passing - Page.User.Identity.Name to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have this url navigation:

```
<telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="View All Employees" NavigateUrl= "../../Employee/ViewAll"  >
```

What i need is to pass 'Page.User.Identity.Name' in the naviagte url - employee/view all to controller below:

```
public ActionResult ViewAll()employees
    {   

        return View(_emp.ViewAll());
    }
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass it to the controller, as it's already accessible from there.

```
var name = User.Identity.Name
```